# When running python file from C# in Visual Studio 2015: The specified executable is not valid for this OS platform

Tags: c#, python-2.7

I am trying to run a python script from my C# application.

Attached is a snippet of my code:

```
string output = "";
ProcessStartInfo Script = new ProcessStartInfo();
Script.FileName = File;
Script.Arguments = XMLargs;
Script.UseShellExecute = false;
Script.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Script.RedirectStandardError = true;
try
{
    using (Process process = Process.Start(Script))
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
        {
            output = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   //Error message
}
```

However, every time that I try to run this, I get this error:

> The Specified Executable is not valid for this OS

This happens regardless of what Python script I use.

Further, I can run all Python scripts from the command prompt with no issues.

My development environment is Visual Studio 2015, and I installed the updated Python Tools for Visual Studio 2015.
I'm using 64 bit Python 2.7.

Is there something wrong with the code above?
Or is there something that I need to work out in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Script.FileName = {path to python.exe};
Script.Arguments = {path to your py script} + {args};
```